# How to move an item between blocks jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am a novice developer. I have one problem. Can't move the element between the div.

Code looks like this:

[image]

And it should be like this:

[image]

Comment: please clearly state what your asking, and where you can't move with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery `insertAfter()` for this

```
$('.pagination').insertAfter('#dle-content > div:last-child');
```

Comment: did this:

$('.pagination').insertAfter('#dle-content');

and it worked